# Remove matches when comparing arrays

Tags: arrays, powershell, compare, powershell-4.0

I'd like help comparing two arrays of, say users, and throwing out any users that exist or match in both arrays, and then tossing the results into a final array. For example:

```
###define arrays
$array1 = @("bill","eric","james","sarah")
$array2 = @("bill","scott","sarah","nancy")

###Combine/Filter? arrays and remove users that exist in both arrays
$result = ($array1 + $array2 | some fancy match removal goes here)
$result
eric,james,scott,nancy
```

I want to make sure matches are completely removed from both arrays when combined. So if "sarah" exists in both arrays, I'd like to remove her completely from the final result. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Compare-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849941.aspx) to extract elements that are unique across both source arrays:

```
$result = Compare-Object $array1 $array2 | Select-Object -Expand InputObject
```

Comment: This is fantastic - thank you very much for your help